# Logistic vs Cox PH model : different hypothesis for a single case

Tags: hypothesis-testing, logistic, survival, cox-model

Let's say I'm interested in comparing the apparition of an event in 2 groups.

I could take the problem by 2 ways :

- consider the dates and compute a Cox PH model.
- consider only the proportion of event and perform a logistic regression.

I have the feeling that there is no "good" option here and that those cases answer to different problematics (and so I could perform both to answer those).

The problem is I'm not 100% sure of what is the exact difference between those problematics : null hypothesis in Cox model is that Hazard Ratio is 1 (so there is no association between risks and group), whereas null hypothesis in Logistic regression is that there is no association between apparition of the event and group).

I see there is a difference, but I cannot seem to find a crystal clear explanation of it. **What is the exact difference between these two hypothesis ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I detail in my book *Regression Modeling Strategies*, a binary model should only be used if (1) time to event is not important and (2) every subject who did not suffer the event of interest was followed the same length of time.  The logistic model estimates the odds ratio for a risk factor in predicting occurrence of an event; the Cox model estimates a hazard ratio, which is the ratio of instantaneous event rates at a given time point.  The hazard ratio is also the number such that you raise the survival curve to a power to get between risk factor levels.  Study hazard functions to learn more.

Interestingly, both the binary logistic model and the Cox model were developed by D.R. Cox.

If follow-up (censoring) times vary or you want to distinguish between early and late events (you usually do) then the Cox model or another time-to-event model is for you.